# Prime React Country & City Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, primereact

I want to create dropdown fields containing countries and cities using PrimeReact. I want to provide this with json file. After the country is selected, I want the cities to be listed accordingly. I couldn't find any examples. How can I achieve this?

```
"data" :[
    {
      "code2": "AF",
      "code3": "AFG",
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "capital": "Kabul",
      "region": "Asia",
      "subregion": "Southern Asia",
      "states": [
        {
          "code": "BDS",
          "name": "Badakhshān",
          "subdivision": null
        },
```

Comment: Isn't that this EXACT example: https://primefaces.org/primereact/cascadeselect/

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-shockley-6ljntv?file=/src/demo/AutoCompleteDemo.js 
I want to do it on two different inputs. I was able to make it this far.